# jquery visibility selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, visibility

I'd like to know if there's anything incorrect in the following :

```
    if($('#three').is(':visible')) {
        alert("visible");
    } else {
        alert("hidden");    
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: Why are you asking that? Do you have an unexpected result?

Comment: yes, the else {} statement does not work

Comment: Pehraps its your conceptual definition of visible? How are you hiding it to test the else statement?

Comment: You mean that when your element with id `three` is not visible, then the alert display `visible`?

Comment: which browser? IE and jQuery has some issues with visibility.

Comment: ^^ I'd like to confirm that $('#three').is(':visible') is a check for visibility and returns a true statement if the <div> is visible,isn't it ?

Comment: check updated ans and go to link for more detail

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code seems correct to me. However, `visible` selector on jQuery [defines](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/) a not visible elements if:

- They have a CSS display value of none.
- They are form elements with type="hidden".
- Their width and height are explicitly set to 0.
- An ancestor element is hidden, so the element is not shown on the page.

Is it the case in your test?

Some others importants aspect regarding this selector is that elements with `visibility: hidden` or `opacity: 0` are considered to be visible!

Also, since 1.3.2, this selector has evolved, as [stated in the changelog](http://docs.jquery.com/Release%3ajQuery_1.3.2#%3avisible.2F%3ahidden_Overhauled).

Comment: thanks a lot sir. I wasn't aware of the fac that visibility : hidden is considered to be visible.Is there any way to find out about the visibility state of a <div> ?

thanks

Comment: What you can do is *in addition* to the current test, to also check that `visible: hidden` is not applied to the element...

Answer (score 2):

Better you check this : **[:visible Selector](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/)**

```
<script>
 if( $('#foo').is(':visible') ) {
    // it's visible, do something
}
else {
    // it's not visible so do something else
}

if( $('#foo').is(':hidden') ) {
    // it's hidden, do something
}
else {
    // it's not hidden so do something else
}

</script>
```

Comment: I just wanted to know if a layer was visible or not(in CSS terms)

Comment: @Anant- then just go to link and check

Comment: i'm sorry sir,but that's exactly what doesn't work.  $('#foo').is(':visible') doesn't work with layers which hav visibility:hidden;

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that #three has display attribute set to some default value. E.g. Display="none"